# RegEx for PostgreSQL 'interval' function

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to implement regex validation for value that will be used in my server side to get data where certain timestamp is older (smaller) than `now() - interval 'myValue'`.

pSQL interval function is explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html), and in short it can have values like `2 days`,`3 years`,`12 hours`, but also you can nest more different values like `2 days 6 hours 30 minutes` etc.

I currently have a regex `/^\d+\s(seconds?|minutes?|hours?|days?|weeks?|months?|years?)$/i` that accepts only one value (e.g. `2 days`), but can't figure out how to allow multiple values, and set a rule that a certain string from this group can only be repeated once or not at all.

This regex `/^\d+\s(seconds?|minutes?|hours?|days?|weeks?|months?|years?)(\s\d+\s(seconds?|minutes?|hours?|days?|weeks?|months?|years?))*$/i` allows nesting but also allows repetition of values e.g. `2 days 12 hours 6 hours 2 minutes` which will result in a fatal error in pSQL query.

I tried restricting repetition of values in this group with `\1` and `{0,1}` combination of regex operators but I just can't nail it precisely enough.

NOTE: Regex is unfortunately only way I can validate this value, since I don't have access to server-side controller which receives this value nor do I have access to client-side frontend of this form. I can't just throw exceptions or skip query because it is a part of important cron-job, and must be stable at all time.

(All I have access to is json schema of this value, and therefore can only define regex pattern for it)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `^(?!$)(?:\d+\s+years?)?(?:(?:\s+|^)\d+\s+months?)?(?:(?:\s+|^)\d+\s+weeks?)?(?:(?:\s+|^)\d+\s+days?)?(?:(?:\s+|^)\d+\s+hours?)?(?:(?:\s+|^)\d+\s+minutes?)?(?:\s+\d+\s+seconds?)?$`

Comment: It works for a case `4352 YEARS 2 weeks 4 days 5 days 2 minutes 30 second` (two `days` values next to each other), but does not allow case when you insert 'larger' value after smaller one, e.g. `4352 YEARS 2 weeks 4 days 2 minutes 30 second 3 months` (note that I inserted months at the end, this will work in pSQL but this regex blocks it)

Comment: That regex [does not allow](https://regex101.com/r/htldlR/1) `4352 YEARS 2 weeks 4 days 5 days 2 minutes 30 second`

Comment: Yes, I know.
I wrote 'It works', and by that I meant it does not allow that value :)
But it also does not allow `4352 YEARS 2 weeks 4 days 2 minutes 30 second 3 months` which it should allow

Comment: Try `^(?!.*(second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year).*\1)\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?(?:\s+\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?)*$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/htldlR/2).

Comment: It works perfectly now, great job man, thanks a lot! You can post it as answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sql
^(?!.*(second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year).*\1)\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?(?:\s+\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/htldlR/2)

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year).*\1)` - no `second`, `minute`, `hour` day`,` week`,` month`or`year` string repetition allowed in the whole string
- `\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?` - 1 or more digits, one or more whitespaces, then either `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `week`, `month` or `year`, and then an optional `s` letter
- `(?:\s+\d+\s+(?:second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)s?)*` - zero or more repetition of one or more whitespaces followed with the pattern described above
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. The only complete documentation of the supported values for `interval` is [the implementation](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/timestamp.c;h=3a93e92e4036dc0afe0fcf81ca7251749b599166;hb=HEAD#l875) (the guts are in `ParseDateTime`).

Consider these:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '12 00:12:00';

     interval     
══════════════════
 12 days 00:12:00
(1 row)

SELECT INTERVAL '12 d 12 mins';

     interval     
══════════════════
 12 days 00:12:00
(1 row)

SELECT INTERVAL '3-2';

    interval    
════════════════
 3 years 2 mons
(1 row)
```

What I would do in your place is to write a function that casts the string to `interval` and catches and reports an error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION interval_ok(text) RETURNS boolean
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   PERFORM CAST ($1 AS interval);
   RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN invalid_datetime_format THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but unfortunately my client wants to insert any value they want, but it's up to me to block them from inserting garbage :). And as I mentioned, this value is part of query that is run by cron job that deletes certain values that are older of what's inserted by client, and query must not fail at any point :(

Comment: Hmm, that is self-contradictory: you must block them from inserting garbage, but it must not fail at any point? It *has* to fail if they are inserting garbage. So you run the values they insert through that function, and you only accept values that are good. That is better than a regular expression in this case.

Comment: How is that self-contradictory? It's up to them to define that time range, that's the requirement from their side. But it is up to me to make sure it works smoothly and never fails, because I can't be sure what do they do on their computers when they are entering value, they can copy-past garbage and accidentally insert 2 duplicated values and query breaks apart. Regex above posted by @Wiktor Stribiżew does exactly that thing.

Comment: Ok, then let's not worry. You have your solution.